# Which gambits do engines rate positively?

Tags: opening, engines, gambits

I often hear about "dubious" gambits - those that may be successful against mediocre opponents, but with correct preparation or against an engine are inaccurate.

Which gambits do the engines rate as either the best or almost-best move in the given situation? That is, which are the non-dubious gambits, according to engine analysis?

Comment: does the queen's "gambit" count? since it's not a "true gambit"

Comment: I hear that engines favor the Halloween Gambit with prejudice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/are-there-any-gambits-which-yield-an-advantage-for-the-side-down-material

Comment: Queens Gambit is probably your best bet...but its not really a gambit. Generally speaking No gambits are positively evaluated unless the opponent accepts it.

Comment: The obvious answer for a "true gambit" would be the Marshall Gambit in the Ruy Lopez.

Comment: That duplicate is not the same as this question. It is more specific: asking about gambits that are accepted, and don't immediately regain the lost material. My question does not have these stipulations.

Answer (score 3):

I will start by some gambits which are legitimate tries for advantage (for white) or for equality (for black) - so gambits which are not dubious as in they are as good as possible.

Most common example is **Marshall attack** in Ruy lopez, which is today studied so well it's practically book draw. White players commonly today play anti-marshall lines to dodge it.

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "16"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 O-O 8. c3 d5
```

In Semi-Slav complex there are two very respected gambits. First of them is **Anti-Moscow gambit**, which leads to very irrational positions:

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "14"]


1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 d5 4. Nc3 c6 5. Bg5 h6 6. Bh4 dxc4 7. e4 g5
```

And **Marshall gambit**:

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "11"]
1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 c6 4.e4 dxe4 5.Nxe4 Bb4+ 6.Bd2
```

English and Benoni (due to transposition) players will be familiar with **Kasparov gambit**:

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "12"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. Nf3 cxd4 4. Nxd4 e5 5. Nb5 d5 6. cxd5 Bc5
```

In this line of Phillidor **Shirov gambit** is probably most critical. Position can also be reached through Pirc move order:

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "9"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 Nd7 4. Nc3 Ngf6 5. g4
```

Lets switch to gambits which promise white "merely" equality in case of black best play - so gambits which are not dubious as in they do not lead to worse position.

Most promising of these probably is **Urosov gambit**, even though it is old enough to be considered romantic. Most lines in it promise white at least some advantage, except 4. ... Bb4+, which tends to lead to equalish endgames. Black can easily dodge it though by transposing to open variations of two knights defence.

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "9"]

1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Nf6 3. d4 exd4 4. Nf3 Nxe4 5. Qxd4
```

**Evans gambit** also promises at least equality for white in all lines. However black has available plenty sound defences to choose from.

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "7"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. b4
```

Staying in Italian complex I believe that good old **Møller attack** is still considered book draw:

```
[fen ""]
[Startply "17"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. c3 Nf6 5. d4 exd4 6. cxd4 Bb4+ 7. Nc3 Nxe4 8. O-O Bxc3 9. d5
```